# unity2D C# - player must press two switches to open door

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, 2d

Essentially I have a door trigger event where if the player presses the switch then the door open. I wish however to do it so that if the door associated needs two switches to open well... then it only opens if two switches are pressed. Here is my code for my InteractSwitch

```
public class InteractSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{

    Animator animator;
    public DoorEventTrigger[] doorTriggers;
    public bool pressed;
    private bool down;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        animator = GetComponent <Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D target)
    {
        if (target.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            down = true;
            animator.SetInteger ("SwitchTrig", 1);

            foreach (DoorEventTrigger trigger in doorTriggers)

                if (trigger != null)
                    trigger.Toggle (true);
        }

    }
```

When triggered this event checks for player, shows switch has been pressed then sends a bool to a function called Toggle which handles the operation of the door.

Next I have my DoorEventTrigger event which checks if the bool sent = true. If it is then the door will open. Here is where I am stuck. As seen in the code I have created a array of InteractSwitch which stores the amount of switches I want the player to have pressed before the door will open. I then state that if the length > 1 then this if condition is true and some code will be added here which will then open the door only if the player has selected the InteractSwitch[].length switches. My question is how would I check that all instances of InteractSwitch for this DoorEventTrigger equals true?

Here is my DoorEventTrigger code

```
public void Toggle (bool val)
{
        if (switchTriggers.Length > 1) {
        Debug.Log ("HAS THIS ACTUALLY DONE ANYTHING");
        door.Open ();
    } 
    else
    {

        if (val)

            door.Open ();
        else

            door.Close ();
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is nowhere near I believe the most efficient answer as it requires code each time u add a new switch but this is what I have

firstly in the InteractSwitch script the bool down is public so it can be accessed by the switchtriggers

```
public bool down;
```

Next is the added code to the Toggle() method

```
public void Toggle (bool val)
{
        if (switchTriggers.Length > 1) {
            if((switchTriggers[0].down == true) && (switchTriggers[1].down == true)){
        Debug.Log ("THIS ACTUALLY DONE SOMETHING!");
        door.Open ();
        }
    } 
    else
    {

        if (val)

            door.Open ();
        else

            door.Close ();
    }


}
```

Now from the public SwitchInteract[]; I know the exact amount of elements in the array however this could be checked through switchTriggers.length; Knowing there is two elements in the array my condition switchTriggers.Length > 1 is correct so next I take the two elements in the array and check if they are down; if BOTH are down then the condition continues and the Debug.Log() validates this. Finally Open() is called which opens the door.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the switches increment or decrement a required switch variable in the door object.

1. Give the door object a requiredSwitch variable.
2. Give each switch a door variable and set it to the door it controls.
3. When a switch is activated, have it decrement its door's requiredSwitch variable.
4. When the door's requiredSwitch variable is 0, then the door opens.
5. You can also have the switches increment the variable if they get deactivated.

This solution allows you to add switches by just setting the door variable of the switch and incrementing the door's initial requiredSwitch variable.